# file size imagemagick thumbnails

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to create thumbnails with imagemagick.. but the file size of the thumbnails is very LARGE!

```
convert -resize 80x80 -quality 70 file.jpg file-thumb.jpg
```

example:

```
file.jpg (1100x825px, 75kb) => file-thumb.jpg (80x60px, 29kb)
```

It just don't give any sense the thumbs ends up so large!? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to specify a filter to maximize compression.

Comment: In PHP, you use the `$filter` argument of `Imagick::resizeImage()`.

Comment: yes, but I don't have a clue which filter constant I need to use.. the list never ends

Comment: Alix it looks like the OP is not using Imagick; I assume they are using exec( ). I do not think filter will have much effect; it is more different filters for different jobs. There are new improved filters now but I tend to stick with the defaults. Some of the Imagemagick users are looking into a downsizing filter with sharpening at the moment mainly for digital photos.

Comment: Thinking about it I did some resizing using all the different filters the otherday and in this case the smallest result was Quadratic at 122kb and the largest was point at 148kb. So you are correct @AlixAxel and filters do have an effect on filesize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
convert file.jpg -thumbnail 80x80 -quality 70 file-thumb.jpg
```

This strips all EXIF data etc. but keeps the color profile.

Note the image is read in first.